# How do I assign a website URL as the value of a selected radiobutton in a Python GUI using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I currently have an assignment for University where I have to develop a GUI using Tkinter in Python which displays multiple options whose purpose is display certain information based on what radio button is selected.

My question is, how do I assign something like a website value to a radio button selection?

I want to assign a different website to each of my 3 radio buttons which is the main source used when I press on any of the options.

For example, I have display details as one of my options, and I wish for that widget when pressed to open a website depending on which radio button is selected.

Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) Please [edit] your post to include the code you've tried. Also, see [what kind of questions are allowed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understood from your question is that you want to use a button in tkinter to make you access a certain website.

I would like to suggest this :

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import Button, Tk

root = Tk()

def web(site):    #function that opens a website in a new window
    webbrowser.open(site, new = 2)    #new = 2 means new window, 1 means new tab, 0 means replace the current window

b = Button(root, text = "google", command = lambda : [web("www.google.com")])
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope it helps you in your current assignment, good luck !

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have figured out my initial issue, now I just have to work out how to call my radio buttons as variables, plan is to use an IF statement to figure out which radiobutton is pressed which changes where the options take me